# mysql insert into table doesnt work

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to do the following insertion below. When I just take the string, MZ�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��\0\0�\0\0\0, and directly put it into the insert statement, it works. However, when i get it through my function and then try to insert, i get an empty set when  select everything form that table.

```
   if($_FILES)//check if cookies set
{
    require_once 'DBLogin.php';
    $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
    if($conn -> connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
    $username = $_REQUEST['uname'];
    //echo "admin: ".$_SESSION['admin']."<br>";


        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $_POST['mname']))
        {
            echo "Invalid malware name. Only Numbers and Letters allowed". "<br>";
            exit();
        }
        else if(!isset($_SESSION['check']) || !isset($_COOKIE['token']) ||$_SESSION['check'] !== hash('ripemd128', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_COOKIE['token']))
        {
            echo "Need to login as Admin before can upload files.<br>";
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            verifyAdmin($conn);
            $fileGood = checkFile($_FILES);
            $entry = getSection($fileGood);

            $entry = chooseSanitization($conn,$entry, $_FILES['file']['type']);
            //$entry = mysql_entities_fix_string($conn,$entry);



            if(checkExistence($conn, $_POST['mname'],$entry) === true)
            {
                echo "Malware sequence and/or name already in database. Please upload different name/sequence. <br>";
                exit();
            }

            $title = $_POST['mname'];


            $insertQuery = "Insert into malwarelist (malwareName, sequence) values ('$title','$entry')";

            //$insertQuery = "Insert into malwarelist (malwareName, sequence) values ('$title','MZ�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��\0\0�\0\0\0')";
            $conn -> query($insertQuery);

            echo "Malware has been added! <br>";
        }
    $conn->close();
}

function chooseSanitization($connection,$string, $fileType)
{
    if ($fileType === 'text/plain')
    {
        return mysql_entities_fix_string($connection,$string);
    }
    else
    {
        return mysql_fix_string($connection,$string);
    }
}

function mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $string)
{
    return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($connection, $string));
}
function mysql_fix_string($connection, $string)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
    return $connection->real_escape_string($string);
}
```

If i try to do "Insert into malwarelist (malwareName, sequence) values ('$title','MZ�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��\0\0�\0\0\0')" it works, but if i try to do this: Insert into malwarelist (malwareName, sequence) values ('$title','$entry')". FYI, $entry is equal to MZ�\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��\0\0�\0\0\0, but nothing is inserted. why?

Comment: WHERE clause can’t be used while inserting data into the database as the it is used only when we need to read or update any value(s) in the database. Try to avoid WHERE clause, 2nd last line of your post

Comment: I'm not using a where caluse. the "where" is just a connecting statement to tell everyone that $entry is equal to what value. i don't use it in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing variables title and entry directly as a string, you need to concatenate the variable using '.' operator
Try with this, may this help You-

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO malwarelist (malwareName, sequence) VALUES('".$_POST['mname'].'',''.$entry."')";
if ($conn->query($insertQuery) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br>New record successfully inserted  ".$_POST['mname'];
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insertQuery. "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

If any of error occurs, comment that error to this answer

To change encoding run the MySQl query on your localhost

```
ALTER TABLE malwarelist MODIFY COLUMN sequence VARCHAR(255)  
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE malwarelist MODIFY COLUMN sequence VARCHAR(255)  
    CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I got this error:  incorrect string value for column sequence. My sequence column is of type varchar(100)

Comment: You need to change the encoding from UTF-8 to  utf8mb4

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: I have edited my answer and provided you the way of how to change the encoding, check it out

Answer (score 0):

It should like below only, you can't add where criteria in an insert statement.

> Insert into malwarelist (malwareName, sequence) values ('$title','$entry')";

Comment: I didnt add a where clause? where do you see that?

Comment: @QuestionAsker123 It was there in original question. Anyways you have modified it, that's good.